# [SpringBoot Exception]: Consider defining a bean of type Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Main Repository File

```
@Repository
public interface myRepository extends JpaRepository<myRepoEntity, Integer>,myRepositoryCustom
```

============================================
Custom Repository

```
public interface myRepositoryCustom {
@Modifying
@Transactional
void updateSomething(SomeDTO someDTO);

}
```

============================================

Implementation for Custom repo method

```
@Repository
public class myRepositoryImpl implements myRepositoryCustom {
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
@Override
public void updateSomething(SomeDTO someDTO) {
    /**
    */some logic
    **/

}
}
```

=====================================================

Service class

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceClass
{
@Autowired
private myRepository myRepository;

}
```

Getting Exception on myRepository
Consider defining a bean of type myRepository and it's not occuring on every startup it occurs out of blue.

I tried Running multiple times faced issue with replication it on test servers This is is not consistent
Tried adding componentScan although my project is in single root directory.
Tried creating Setter with Autowired annotation to define Bean

Expecting a possible scenerio where bean can throw this error && which is not consistent

```
[2022-03-25 10:42:19.221] [] [] [] [fa060258] [WARN] 
[SpringBootAPPNAME] 
[o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh] - Exception 
encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh 
attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:     
Error creating bean with name 'ribbonClientConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 
'propertiesFactory'; nested exception is 
:org.springframework.beans.factory.
BeanCreationNotAllowedException: 
Error creating bean with name 'propertiesFactory': Singleton bean 
creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in 
destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a 
destroy method implementation!) 



`***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
 ***************************

 Description:

 Field myRepository in com.myapp.Service.SomeServiceClass 
 required a bean of type 'com.myapp.repository.myRepository' that 
 could not be found.


 Action:

 Consider defining a bean of type 
 'com.myapp.repository.myRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Please put a screen shot of exception details.

Comment: Please post the details of the exception raised, but paste as text instead of image.

Comment: Added the Exception as Text as discussed in comments

Comment: is there any reason why you have used \< an in your /> in your Custom Repository ? Is it just a typo or something else ?

Comment: That escape character was added while copying it in stackoverflow that’s not in code ..it’s a typo

Comment: @BessemManita Please don't ask people to post screenshots of textual data. Exception stacktraces, code, etc should all be posted as code-formatted *text*, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Add component scan for repository package

Comment: All packages are under same base class so implicit component scan will work in this case. It’s fetching other beans annotated with @ Repository @ Service etc..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).